# Android Studio, Flutter, continuous loop trying to sync files

Tags: android-studio, flutter, lag

**Steps to reproduce:**
1. new flutter project
2. next
3. change the package name 
4. finish

**Result:** Every 2 seconds Android Studio freezes, tries to sync files and interrupts my typing!

**Expected Result:** You know.

**Temporary Workaround:** Download older version: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

To circumvent this momentary problem I'm going to create a new project and port over the code.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled Android Studio, invalidated the cache and have reproduced this error on new projects.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76453358

Build: 3.1, AI-173.4670197, 201803220120,

AI-173.4670197, JRE 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Windows 7(amd64) v6.1 Service Pack 1, screens 1920x1080, 1920x1080

Android Gradle Plugin: 3.0.1
Gradle: (gradle version information not found)
NDK: from local.properties: (not specified); latest from SDK: (not found); 
LLDB: pinned revision 3.1 not found; latest from SDK: (package not found); 
CMake: from local.properties: (not specified); latest from SDK: (not found); from PATH: (not found);

Comment: Related to this issue on the GitHub flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15440

Comment: thank you so much, i had no idea, i checked here and on twitter.

Comment: devoncarew commented 7 minutes ago: "We're releasing a new version of the plugin shortly which will address this; thanks for your patience!"

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1735 and already fixed

Comment: Six minutes ago devoncarew (from the Flutter team) said: "We're releasing a new version of the plugin shortly which will address this; thanks for your patience!"

Answer (score 0):

they fixed it in their next update https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1735

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to solve this :As mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1735) you just need to remove folder named

> .idea

from your project root directory .

**UPDATE**

Try to **

---

** instead of this kind of tricks. They published a light update patch to solve a couple of bugs such as this.